# Resetting xpos on mouseup / touchup events

Tags: html, css, ontouch, mouseup

I have a issue after a lengthy battle with simply assigning the touch events to a image slider.

I now have a working touchscreen image slider but the only problem is that when I touchscreen the movement position begins from the center of the div and moves the whole div to be positioned with the pointer in the middle and lift off screen - and then attempt to do another movement. The movement position begins again in the center of the div.

I know I need to reset the co-ords somehow when I lift off screen, or maybe unbind, but I have no idea how to do this.

Here is a little HTML for the divs:

```
.container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  width:500px;
  height:100%;
}

.drag{
  position: absolute;
  top:1%; 
  left:0%;
  width:100%;
  height:15%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  border-style: solid; 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  z-index:1000;
}

</head>

<body>

<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id='drag' class='drag'><!---video area--->

  some images

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the swipe events.

```
var dom = {
    container: document.getElementById("container"),
    drag: document.getElementById("drag"),
}
var container = {
    x: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    w: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    h: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().height
}
var drag = {
    w: dom.drag.offsetWidth 
}

target = null;

document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchCancel, false);

function handleTouchStart(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        target = touch.target;
    }
}
function handleTouchMove(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        if(target ===  dom.drag) {
            moveDrag(e);
        }
    }
}
function handleTouchEnd(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 0) { // User just took last finger off screen
        target = null;
    }
}
function handleTouchCancel(e) {
    return;
}

function moveDrag(e) {
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var posX = touch.pageX - container.x - drag.w / 2;


    dom.drag.style.left = posX + "px";

}
```

Comment: here is a fiddle, if you move the element, the position of the touch will allways be centred in the div. how do i start drag from anywhere within the element so that i am not having to start from center everytime... i know it is down to this     var posX = touch.pageX - container.x - drag.w / 2;   but iv tried everything and nothing has made it possible to drag from anywhere, its allways from a certain point defined by this line of code...   FIDDLE... http://jsfiddle.net/xbmyazb2/20/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xbmyazb2/20/